# CSS styling in order to properly align img's the way I want them to on my page?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm horrible with CSS styling. I'm trying to align these logo's here:

```
      <a href="https://geo.music.apple.com/us/album/_/1460176267?mt=1&app=music&at=1000lHKX">
          <img id="apple" src={apple}></img>
      </a>
      <a href="https://open.spotify.com/album/6ITBoE1l1zPCtXKOTN12IC">
          <img id="spotify" src={spotify}></img>
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.pandora.com/artist/various-artists/love-hart-presents-hartfm-explicit/AL2V7Pb7xcg7p74">
          <img id="pandora" src={pandora}></img>
      </a>
      <a href="https://listen.tidal.com/album/107846023">
          <img id="tidal" src={tidal}></img>
      </a>
```

On somewhere else within my page (they stay on the top left), but when I try to apply CSS rules as such:

```
#apple {
  top: 75%;
  left: 34.5%;
  width: 4%;
  height: 4%;
}

#spotify {
  width: 3.5%;
  height: 3.5%;
}

#pandora {
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 6%;
  height: 8%;
}

#tidal {
  width: 4%;
  height: 4%;
}
```

They don't actually move. Not sure what to do here.

Comment: should it be aligned vertically or horizontally?

Comment: Have you tried absolute positioning them? i.e. `position: absolute;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrapped all of your a tags in a div and gave it an id="parent" and these each seem to work to do something you might want?

Not sure exactly what or how you want things "aligned" though so I offer some options below. Hopefully one of these is what you're looking for and you don't need your tops, lefts, etc. and can just use your width and height properties for sizing the a tags.

```
#parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#parent {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
}

#parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```